How to make our Android app become an approved source (e.g known source)
We are developing our own app store for white-label devices.
Our app store should be able install other apps by downloading APK from our server.
However, when our app store tries to install an APK, Android always display dialog asking user to allow to install app from unknown sources. That is not what we want. We want own app store is a known source so that Android will not annoy users when installing APKs.
My questions are:

How Android check whether our app store is known or unknown source?
Without rooting, is it possible to make our app store become a approved source or known source?


What permissions are you requesting in your manifest? How do those permissions compare with those of apps that can do what you seek, such as F-Droid?
